# How do mimick html checkbox array with asp.net checkbox control?

Tags: asp.net, forms, checkbox, servercontrols

I need to send an array of checkbox values to a form on submit. Right now I am using plain old html, so it looks something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" />
```

The problem with the above is that it doesn't maintain viewstate on postback, so I want to substitute that using the  control (not the list, but the regular checkbox control).

The reason I don't want to use a list is because it is hard to tweak the layout and position.

Comment: This may be a silly answer, but why not just use a `CheckBoxList` component?

Comment: Because formatting and position the labels and check boxes is a pain in the ass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to stick with regular html form checkboxes on this one... I lose the viewstate, but it was better than the alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the normal checkboxlist but add an adapter to chenge the rendered output. 
Here's one: 
http://code.google.com/p/aspnetcontroladapters/wiki/CheckBoxList